# Performance Testing - Are there any automation tools for performance testing that renders webpages in browser?

Tags: performance-testing, ui-automation, browser-automation

All the performance testing tools I found do not use actual browsers for UI testing. Some of them will get the html of the webpage from the server and will parse it and we can verify the elements on them.

What I want is to find the time it takes to render the web pages and elements in actual browsers when multiple users are logged into the application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute majority of web tools act on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level and not kicking off the real browsers because:

1. For performance testing of the **backend** (simulating hundreds/thousands of concurrent users) you don't need to simulate the real browser, it's sufficient to mimic the real browser network footprint
2. For performance testing of the **frontend** you don't need to conduct high load, single browser is sufficient and its [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) can tell pretty much everything

If you're still looking for a load testing tool which uses real browsers instead of background threads executing HTTP requests I can think of 2:

1. [LoadRunner](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-professional/overview) with [TruClient](https://marketplace.microfocus.com/appdelivery/content/truclient) protocol
2. [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) with [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/)

however it shouldn't be a problem to add support of browser automation framework like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to any load testing tool which can "understand" a programming language

Answer (score 0):

If you are up to a little programming, you can use [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) or similar headless browser engines. [This URL](https://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html) has some interesting names, links and projects.

If screenshots are useful, then a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=automated%20webpage%20screenshot%20tool) gives a lot of results. I saw an excellent Google Tech Talk on a project call [dpxdt](https://github.com/bslatkin/dpxdt). (This is just in case someone wants to explore the screenshot angle)